# How can I add custom suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How do I add it so when I type a word lets say "key" it changes it into lets say "key hole" (dumb example I know) in VS Code?

I have tried looking in the settings and haven't got any farther then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simple case of what you've shown above, you can just [write a custom snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets). (see the `Snippets: Configure User Snippets` command in the command palette) Ex.

```json
{
    "key": {
        "prefix": "key",
        "body": "key hole",
        // "scope": "java" // uncomment to make it only apply for Java files
    }
}
```

I don't think suggestions (outside of snippets) are configurable with vanilla (no extensions) VS Code aside from writing or using an extension that facilitates that.

Answer (score 0):

snippets can be used if you have complex text segments with fields.

if you just want text replacement have a look at

[Complete from File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.complete-from-file)

Answer (score -1):

#### [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions)

> It can also serve as an alternative to fixed text snippets. You can construct a number of `include`/`import` statements at the start of a new file for the actions that do not have a `diagnostics` property.

*[Create your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets) can also helpful.*